# extract variables from find first

Tags: cakephp

I want to prepopulate some field values for a new record. I can hard code them in as you see below but I cant extract them from the $lesson array and I cant get them from hidden fields when i set the variables in the view. 
In the find I get the values I need so what is the method I use to extract the variables from the find first?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html

```
      $lesson=$this->set( 'lesson',$this->Lesson->find('first',$options));

       if ($this->request->is('post')) {

         $this->TrequestAmend->create();
   $this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['lesson_id']=6; //I want o set this value to lesson_id found in find first above but how???
               $this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['tutor_id']=2;
                $this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['student_id']=2;



            if ($this->TrequestAmend->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your Tutor Requested Amended data has been saved.'));
               // return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'displayall'));
            }
            else
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
       }

//     view 
echo $this->Form->input($lessonId, array('type' => 'hidden'));
    echo $this->Form->input($tutorId, array('type' => 'hidden'));
   echo $this->Form->input($stId, array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

Comment: Don't understand your question/code.

Comment: if you look at my code I am setting the value like this $this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['lesson_id']=6; I dont want to do this as I want to set this from the find first but how do I get the fields from find first in the controller?

Comment: you are working with `Lesson` or `TrequestAmend` model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lesson = $this->Lesson->find('first', $options);
$this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['lesson_id'] = $lesson['Lesson']['id'];

$this->set(compact('lesson'));
```

Comment: This doesnt work at all. The lesson id gets printed out in the view but I cant access it in the controller? Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'lesson_id' cannot be null for $this->request->data['TrequestAmend']['lesson_id'] = $lesson['Lesson']['id']; The lesson id is returning a null value but that isnt true as it has a value?

Comment: I cant find the answer? what is going here as I cant even  get a debug value even though it displays in the view??????$lesson=$this->set( 'lesson',$this->Lesson->find('first',$options));
      
            debug($lesson);

Comment: 1) please take some time to learn PHP in general.  This will greatly help your attempts at CakePHP.  2) I've changed the code slightly to something you could have debugged yourself.  Simply debug() or print_r() the $lesson variable to see where the lesson's id is.

Comment: Please dont make comments like that. I know your trying to help but it doesnt serve any purpose in assuming the obvious wasnt done. debug($lesson) was returning NULL but I could view the variables in the View. I will check your code thanks .

Comment: Based on your comments, I think my comment is valid.  If you're getting data passed to the view, there is data in the variable.  Echo it, Debug it, Print it...whatever, but try something or explain what hasn't worked.

Comment: I have already said i debug the find first lesson variable $lesson and get null from controller. I want to access a variable from lesson var  in controller but i cant

Comment: Is debug mode on?  If it is, there's something else you're not including.

Comment: I am not on debug mode and i tested another variable with debug and that worked. Find first variable didnt debug?

Comment: I will send code when i get home but i couldnt display the variable with find first

Comment: Here is the code in the controller. It wont show the value for $lesson as it is NULL. However in View it displays the whole array as expected. There is something wrong with displaying this $lesson variable in the controller? $lesson=$this->set( 'lesson',$this->Lesson->find('first',$options));
      
          
               $student_id=2;
             
            debug($student_id);
              debug($lesson);

Answer (score 0):

If set values to `$this->request->data` of model `TrequestAmend` you have to make sure that you created form for this model using (I write this because you haven't posted this line here).

```
echo $this->Form->create('TrequestAmend');
```

Then you have to change variables in view when you creating form inputs to its names. So do it as follows:

```
echo $this->Form->input('lesson_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('tutor_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('student_id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
```

And thats all, now you should be able to prepopulate form.

Comment: I did already have the the line in to create in the view. I get the values from the find first that I want to add in the form to save. isnt there  a way to simply extract values from the find first in the controller as above instead of having to extract them in the view and display them as hidden? seems find first is hard to work with once you have the data.

Comment: If table fields are the same like in your form, you can just find items and put them directly to `$this->request->data`. So `$this->request->data = $resultOfFind;`.

Comment: Do you mean find 1 field at a time ? I also need to add some new fields from the find so I cant just make the request->data = resultoffind

Comment: No I mean you could perform your find on all fields you want and then put it into `$this->request->data`. Only requirement is to cover fields from db with this from form. So you can perform find at first and then add some other fields or use `array_merge()`.